# JPA 2.0: Embedded object exclusive to one entity

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

**Is there a possibility in JPA 2.0 to asure that an embedded object is embedded with only one object, but not several?**

In my case I have an `Address` that I can assign to a `Customer`. I want every customer to use its own address object and would like to create a constraint that makes sure that no two customers share the actually same object.

My code looks like this:

```
@Entity
public Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    // ..   
}

@Embeddable
public Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;

    // ..
}
```

Currently, if I create two customers and assign them the same `Address` object, then persist and read them, they again share the object with the same identity. I want to prohibit saving such customers that share addresses with other customers.

Comment: If I understand your point, you would want to create a unique address entry even if it's address is same in terms of data?

Comment: @Phani Exactly. Future changes to the address should affect only the one customer that holds that address and not have any side-effects on other customers. One Java-way of solving this would be creating a copy of the address when setting it (I assume), but I'm looking for a JPA-based solution.

Comment: If you didn't override the equals method, it should ideally store 2 entries to database. Please check the sql generated for the action to identify what's causing it to be stored as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest approach in this case is to create a copy of `Address` object in `Customer.setAddress()`.

Also, I'm not sure that different `Customer`s can share `Address` with the same identity when retrieved from the database. Perhaps you get the same objects from the session cache because you save and read them in the same session.

Answer (score 1):

It is the nature of the @Embedded mechanism that embedded instances of an embeddable class are NEVER shared among different instances of the enclosing class. If you observed this behavior in your code, it must have been because you were accessing cached data during reading from the entity manager.
So, even if you assign the same instance of an embeddable class to multiple instances of the enclosing class, then "persist()", then destroy the entity manager and EntityManagerFactories, or invalidate the caches "entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll()", then create a new EntityManager and "find()" the enclosing objects, each of them should have their own instance of (in your case) "Address" objects, even if their content is the same.

The JPA spec says the following about embedded objects in section 2.5:

> [...] Instances of these classes, unlike entity instances, do not have
>   persistent identity of their own. Instead, they exist only as part of
>   the state of the entity to which they belong. [...]

If your JPA implementation doesn't adhere to that, it isn't really JPA standards-compliant...